# Azure Linux server not responding

Tags: ubuntu, azure, putty, azure-connect

I installed Lamp server and phpmyadmin on my linux azure server but phpmyadmin was not working. I restarted the system and now I am unable to connect to it. Putty returns error saying " connection rejected" . Even I am unable to ping this server from my command prompt.

Also this forum [(http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/ssh-into-linux/)](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/ssh-into-linux/) says that I have to get a private key for authentication. If this is the case, from where I can get a private key using my windows system? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already used the machine, you already have all the information you need to connect to the Virtual Machine via SSH. If you created the VM using the Quick Create option in the management portal, you created a password-based VM - easy.

If you cannot connect using the same `ssh` command you used before, then perhaps the machine is hung or went down.

In the portal, find the VM, select it, and use the Restart option to reset it. Try connecting again to the machine in a few minutes.